# Android: JSoup - парсинг страницы

Tags: android, html, java

Только недавно познакомился с JSoup и вообще с парсингом веб-страниц (до этого не работал в этом направлении). 
И появилась такая проблема. Вот код на сайте:

```
<div class="marquee"><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="1">
Тест1 &mdash; <a href="/translation/am">ы1 </a>
 // Тест2 &mdash; <a href="/translation/rub">ы2</a>
 // Тест3 &mdash; <a href="/translation/zen">ы3</a>
 // Тест4 &mdash; <a href="/translation/met">ы4</a>
 // Тест5 &mdash; <a href="/translation/vi">ы5</a>
 // Тест6 &mdash; <a href="/translation/a">ы6</a>
 // Тест7 &mdash; <a href="/translation/k">ы7</a>
</marquee></div>
```

Так я пытаюсь его пытаюсь парсить:

```
Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://site.com").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements links = doc.select("marquee");
        textView1.setText(links.text());
```

В чём заключается проблема: когда я начинаю парсить по тегу **marquee** то я получаю только сами "// Тест2  - ы2", "// Тест3 -ы3 " и т. д.

А мне нужно получать вместе со ссылками,как оно идёт по порядку.

Больше спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

JSoup на то и html парсер, чтобы Вы могли работать с контекстом, не распарсивая html, тут скорее всего будет то, что вам нужно получить элементы

```
Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
for(Element link : links) {
    System.out.println(link.text());
}
```

а уже ну их брать атрибуты `href`, которые хранят в себе значения самой ссылки

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь, Вы хоть мануал смотрели? У Вас "marquee" - класс. Доступ к класам через точку.
Будет: "div.marquee". Можно смотреть все "а". Например так `"div.marquee а"`